# Determine a norm of the linear functional

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a set of all continuous real valued functions $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ on a compact $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ with supremum norm.

I wish to determine a norm of the functional 
$$
T(f)=\int_a^b f(t)  h(t) dt, f\in X
$$
where $h:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable.

I know that $\|T\| \leq \int_a^b |h(t)|dt$ and $\|T\|=\int_a^b |h(t)|dt$ when instead of $X$ we take $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Look at your proof of $\lVert T\rVert = \int_a^b \lvert h(t)\rvert\,dt$ for $C([a,b])$. Can you modify it to see that the norm remains unchanged? If not, what does it tell you about how much the norm decreases?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $h\geq 0$ (else you can modify this proof). For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n \in X$ be the continuous function such that $f_n(x) = 1$ on $[a+1/n, b-1/n]$, and then drops off to zero on either side of that interval. Then, $\|f_n\| = 1$, and
$$
T(f_n) = \int_a^b f_n(t)h(t)dt \to \int_a^b h(t)dt \geq
$$
Conclude that $\|T\| \geq \int_a^b h(t)dt$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to obtain the general case (when $f$ has both positive and negative values). It will be probably a modification of such a proof: If $|f| \leq 1$ we find (it's Corollary from Luzin's theorem) a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous such that $|f_n|\leq 1$ and $f_n(t)\rightarrow sgn h(x)$ a.e. Then by the Lebessgue's convergence theorem $\|T\| \geq \int_a^b |h(t)|dt$, if additionaly $f_n(a)=f_n(b)$.